# Splitting LuisDialog methods (LuisIntents) into multiple files or categories

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm working on a Microsoft bot framework project where I create a `LuisDialog` to interact with the user. I'm probably going to have a lot of different intents which can be sorted into multiple categories.

What is the best way to organize this?

- Should I make one big `LuisDialog` class with all the `LuisIntent` methods?

  This seems kind of unorganized to me.
- Should I make multiple `LuisDialog` classes for each category?

  This might give a lot of problems. What if I have an intent that should be covered by all categories? How can I make sure the user message is checked by every `LuisDialog`? This is probably not a good idea.
- Should I make one big `LuisDialog` class that somehow 'includes' methods from other files/classes, where each file/class represents a category?

  This seems like a good idea, however, I have no idea how to do this in C#

If you have other suggestions, please let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: I've got the same issue, did you use partial classes or did you use another solution?

Comment: I used partial classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering if there might be a better solution;

Using `partial` classes in C# seems to be the best solution here,
read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/228) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

> Thank you! This seems like a decent solution, however, how can I do
>   context.Wait(MessageReceived) if the MessageReceived method is not
>   accessible from a categoryXHandler class (protected)?

What I would do is I will let the `CategoryHandler` return the **activity** I want to post to user. Please see my code sample (**`HandleCategoryA` method**).

---

Assuming you have

1. `category-A` which has `Intent1`, `Intent2`, `Intent3`, `Intent4`
2. `category-B` which has `Intent1`, `Intent2`
3. `category-C` which has `Intent1`

I think the best way to do is still having one single `LuisDialog`, define **3 methods** to handle each category.

```
public class MyDialog : LuisDialog<string>
{
    [LuisIntent(CategoryA.Intent1)]
    [LuisIntent(CategoryA.Intent2)]
    [LuisIntent(CategoryA.Intent3)]
    [LuisIntent(CategoryA.Intent4)]
    public async Task HandleCategoryA(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var returnActivity = CategoryAHandler.Handle(result); // your business logic will be put inside this method

        await context.PostAsync(returnActivity);
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent(CategoryB.Intent1)]
    [LuisIntent(CategoryB.Intent2)]
    public async Task HandleCategoryB(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        CategoryBHandler.Handle(result); // your business logic will be put inside this method
    }

    [LuisIntent(CategoryC.Intent1)]
    public async Task HandleCategoryC(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        CategoryCHandler.Handle(result); // your business logic will be put inside this method
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a decent solution, however, how can I do `context.Wait(MessageReceived)` if the `MessageReceived` method is not accessible from a categoryXHandler class (protected)?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured using partial classes is the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did this differently.

I have a main Luis Dialog, with the intent detection of all intents.
Based on the intent I am forwarding the message to my 2nd LUIS dialog.
This captures related intents and an empty string intent to "catch all the rest"

If I get to the "all the rest", I set the context.DOne, returning to my root LUIS dialog, which reinterprets the LuisResult received from the 2nd one and handles that.

An example is 'weather' intent. It gets to LuisDialog1
I do a context.forward(new LuisDialog2(), ResumeAfter...)

LuisDialog2() handles also the 'weather' intent, but for example also 'MoreWeather'
If none of those is detected, it gets into the LuisDialog2 [LuisIntent("")] handler method.
This sets a context.Done(luisresultobject) returning to the LuisDialog1 ResumeAfter method where this code resides

```
var lLuisResult = await result as LuisResult;
IntentRecommendation lRecommendation = this.BestIntentFrom(lLuisResult);
await DispatchToIntentHandler(context, null, lRecommendation, lLuisResult);
```

Still not sure about the null parameter, but it is working correctly in all my tests so far

Hope it is clear :(